# how to fix Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php) in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

in my laravel project management application I have project and one project can create many tasks and one task have publish many files regarding to the task. so, in my file attachment form is this in files folder in view file

files/form.blade.php

```
@foreach ($task->project->files as $file)
                <div>
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                        <span>

                            <a href="{{ $file->file_url }}" target="_blank">{{ $file->file_name }}</a>
</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                @endforeach

        <form class="form-vertical" role="form"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                    method="post"
                                    action="{{ route('projects.files', ['projects' => $project->id]) }}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="file" name="file_name" class="form-control" id="file_name">
                @if ($errors->has('file_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('file_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Files</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
```

and file model relationship with Task model is this

```
public function task(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Task model relationship with File model is this

```
public function files(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\File');
}
```

and now I included files/form.blade.php file with tasks/show.blade.php file as this

tasks/show.blade.php

```
<h2>{{ $task->project->project_name }}</h2>
<hr>

{{$task->task_name}}
<hr>

{!!$task->body!!}

<hr>
@include('files.form')
```

then when I try to view task/show.blade.php file this following error is coming

```
Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php)
```

how can fix this problem?

**edited question**

```
public function uploadAttachments(Request $request, $id)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'file_name'     => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,pdf|between:1,7000',
        ]);

        $filename     = $request->file('file_name')->getRealPath();

        Cloudder::upload($filename, null);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

        $fileUrl = Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height" => $height]);
        $this->saveUploads($request, $fileUrl, $id);

        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Your Attachment has been uploaded Successfully');
    }

    private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id)
    {
        $file = new File;
        $file->file_name  = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
        $file->project_id = $id;
       // $file->task_id = $taskId;
        $file->save();
    }
```

**New edited question**

this is my comment form and this is working well here

comments/form.blade.php

```
@foreach ($task->project->comments as $comment)

    <div>
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    <span>{{ $comment->comments }} by
                       <span style="font-style: italic;color: #09f;">
                       {{ ($comment->user()->first()->username === auth()->user()->username) ? 'You' : $comment->user()->first()->username }} 
                       </span>
                    </span></div>
                    <a href="/projects/{{ $task->project->id }}/comments/{{ $comment->id }}/edit">Edit</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete pull-right"
                      data-action="/projects/{{ $task->project->id }}/comments/{{ $comment->id }}"
                      data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
                <hr/>

@endforeach
```

and include with tasks/show.blade.php

```
@include('comments.form')
@include ('files.form')
```

my comments form is working but file form is not working....

Comment: no any idea about this matter

Comment: need some help..

Comment: please see my edited question

Comment: what is your controller returning with the `view()` method?

Comment: I did not use controller view method

Comment: without that how you are passing the data? to the blade template?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: I used @include('files.form')

Comment: @include is just for view binding, how you have to bind view to controller and route is there in the above url.

Comment: but my other include file is working well with@include and not any view method

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code, but simple laravel works in this way

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('app.tasks', TaskController@index);

// Model [App]
class App {
    public $fillable  = ['name'];

    public function task(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }
}

// Controller
class TaskController {
    public function index() {
       $app = App::get();
       return view('home.app', ['app' => $app]); // resources/view/home/app.blade.php
    }
}

// resources/view/home/app.blade.php

<div>{{ $app->name }}</div>
<div>{{ $app->task()->id }}</div>
```